# Obtener Resultado equipo ganador

Tags: javascript

Tengo un caso donde se calcula el puntaje mayor y se obtiene el equipo ganador.
1 - usuario ingresa los equipos.
2 - usuario ingresa puntuación.
El resultado es obtener la puntuación mayor y el equipo ganador.

Hasta el momento estoy obteniendo el resultado mayor, pero tengo problemas en obtener el equipo ganador del `input`.

Este es mi `HTML`.

```js
function Calcular() {
  var p1 = document.getElementById('p1').value;
  p1 = parseInt(p1);
  var p2 = document.getElementById('p2').value;
  p2 = parseInt(p2);
  var p3 = document.getElementById('p3').value;
  p3 = parseInt(p3);

  var p = [p1, p2, p3];

  var mayor = null;
  var ganador = null;

  for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    if (mayor < p[i]) {
      mayor = p[i]
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = mayor;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label>Equipos:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtequipo1" id="equipo1"></td>
    <td><label>Puntaje :</label></td>
    <td>
      <select name="cbotipo" id="p1">
        <option>10</option>
        <option>20</option>
        <option>30</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>Equipos:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtequipo2" id="equipo2"></td>
    <td><label>Puntaje :</label></td>
    <td>
      <select name="cbotipo" id="p2">
        <option>10</option>
        <option>20</option>
        <option>30</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>Equipos:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtequipo3" id="equipo3"></td>
    <td><label>Puntaje :</label></td>
    <td>
      <select name="cbotipo" id="p3">
        <option>10</option>
        <option>20</option>
        <option>30</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>Resultado</label></td>
    <td><label id="resultado"></label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="cont-controles">
  <input type="submit" name="btnBoton" value="calcular Puntaje " class="btn-buscar" onclick="Calcular()" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo así:

```js
function Calcular() {
  // seleccionamos todos los elementos que select que empiezen con el id p "p1" "p2" etc.
  var p = document.querySelectorAll('select[id^="p"]');
  var mayor = 0;
  var ganador = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    if (mayor < p[i].value) {
      mayor = p[i].value;
      // selecctionamos al padre del select "td" y luego a su padre "tr"
      // a partir de ahi buscamos un input y optenemos su valor          
      ganador = p[i].parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("input").value;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = "ganador es " + ganador + " con: " + mayor;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><label>Equipos:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtequipo1" id="equipo1"></td>
    <td><label>Puntaje :</label></td>
    <td>
      <select name="cbotipo" id="p1">
        <option>10</option>
        <option>20</option>
        <option>30</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>Equipos:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtequipo2" id="equipo2"></td>
    <td><label>Puntaje :</label></td>
    <td>
      <select name="cbotipo" id="p2">
        <option>10</option>
        <option>20</option>
        <option>30</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>Equipos:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="txtequipo3" id="equipo3"></td>
    <td><label>Puntaje :</label></td>
    <td>
      <select name="cbotipo" id="p3">
        <option>10</option>
        <option>20</option>
        <option>30</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>Resultado</label></td>
    <td><label id="resultado"></label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="cont-controles">
  <input type="submit" name="btnBoton" value="calcular Puntaje " class="btn-buscar" onclick="Calcular()" />
</div>
```